# Absorbance spectrum of common metal oxides

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, absorption

I am looking into metal oxides particles, and I wonder where can I find the absorbance spectrum of visible light of common avaiable metal oxides?

Comment: Have you tried googling 'metal oxide absorption spectrum'?

Comment: https://refractiveindex.info/ has a lot of curves. Choose a book that has $\kappa$ in it to have the absorption spectrum (and that covers the visible). Here is for example alumina/sapphire (AlO2), ordinary axis: https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=Al2O3&page=Querry-o

Comment: @JoséAndrade excuse my question, but how do I go from refraction to absorption?? I read "Extinction coefficient" is that the absorption of light?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I actually would like to find oxides which have peak absorption at around 450 nm

Comment: @Francesco https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Complex_refractive_index yes, $\kappa$ (extinction coefficient or absorption coefficient) is the unit that quantifies the absorption properties of a medium.